# Magento 2: optimization

Tags: magento2.3, optimization, pagespeed

I am facing issue with Magento 2 optimization server response [image: Response time issue]

What are the measures that are required to fix this

My current Magento version in 2.3.4 running on the Cloudflare server

Comment: Your site takes 30 seconds to load - that's not good! Are you using Varnish? Are all your cache's configured correctly and enabled?

Comment: I am using default magento 2 cache

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Enable Flat Categories and Products ( Before doing this take a backup of the database )

Step 2: Merge CSS and JS Files and also enable the option of loading js at bottom

Step 3: Content Delivery Network ( ask server spoke person or use Imageengine for image )

Step 4: Caching ( Enable FPC if possible, use Memcache or Redis for the database, Ask to sever for any host cache they provide or for opcache enable and make use of it )

Step 5: Image Optimization ( Use any image optimization extension or just do it manually if you get it done by CDN well and good )

Step 6: Enable Compression ( Use Gzip, extend cache time for static content,  )

Step 7: Reduce Server Response Time (Use Varnish HTTP Cache if server provide, Or just buy full page cache warmer)

Step 8: Magento Updates ( this is up to you but make sure all the latest security patches is applied )

Step 9: Make use of Critical CSS

Please Do check my website: https://nileshdubey.com/magento2/how-to-speed-up-magento-2/

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

- Varnish is a must have.
- Effective use of Redis too is recommended.
- Advance Bundle JS ( this will reduce render blockers to an extent )
- Implement Critical CSS concept
- Picture tag and device based images.
- CDN
- Cache Life
- Move JS to footer
- Dedicated server or VPS
- Page to be delivered from cache in most cases.
  You should be able to get FCP  < 1 second easily
  LCP < 3 seconds( this is a web Vital )

There are other tweak's but first take care of the above.